# Microsoft Hex dates

Tags: postgresql, datetime, type-conversion

I have the following from a Microsoft SQL Server database for date/time value:

```
0x00009CEF00A25634
```

I found this post:
[Help me translate long value, expressed in hex, back in to a date/time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610603/help-me-translate-long-value-expressed-in-hex-back-in-to-a-date-time)

Which seemed to be on the right track but by using the code I didn't get the right dates, are my hex dates in a different format? How would I convert them to a normal date, I am using PHP/PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`select CAST (0x00009CEF00A25634  as datetime)` gives `2009-12-30 09:51:03.000`

This is two integers. One for the date part `0x00009CEF` (decimal 40175) and one for the time part `00A25634` (decimal 10638900). The date part is a signed integer giving number of days since 1 Jan 1900. The time part is an integer representing number of ticks.

There are 300 ticks in a second.

It can be seen that the following also returns the same result

```
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND,10638900*10/3.0, DATEADD(DAY,40175, '19000101'))
```

You will need to figure out how to apply this to `postgres`.

Edit: an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19589641/73226)  apparently does this. I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: thanks for your answer it seems to makes sense, but i cant seem to cast as datetime in postgresql, i just get  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "x00009CEF00A25634"
LINE 1: select CAST (0x00009CEF00A25634 as datetime)

Am i being thick? please tell me if I am :)

Comment: @user754703 - This is SQL Server's internal format. The `SELECT` statements above are run in SQL Server. You will need to figure out how to apply the logic in this answer using `php` or `postgres` functions as I'm not very familiar with either of these.

Comment: i have ran the statement select CAST (0x00009CEF00A25634 as datetime) in both mysql and postgresql using phpmyadmin, phppgadmin and logged in to the postgresql server via command line and all have the error....could it be my postgresql installation? I am on psql (8.4.7)

Comment: @user754703 - That statement will **only** work in SQL Server. You'll need to see what functions are available for working with binary data in your RDBMS. My answer just explains how to decode the `datetime` format.

Comment: thanks for your help martin, i will have to do a php conversion i think using the logic you provided. I have also found in the table a hex date in this format.... 0x9CD1030D, is this just for the date part only without the time?

Comment: Difficult to guess what that is. If the source was a `datetime` column it would always be 8 bytes irrespective of whether or not the time part was zero.

Comment: @user754703: That might be `smalldatetime` turned `varbinary`. The following returns a reasonable result of `2009-11-30 13:01:00`: `SELECT CAST(0x9CD1030D AS smalldatetime)`. Retroactively, the high word, `0x9CD1`, most likely represents the date part, while the low word, `0x030D`, seems to be the number of minutes since midnight.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me while migrating from SQL to MySQL :

```
SELECT (CAST('1900-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX( 0x0000A249004576D0 ),1,8), 16, 10) AS SIGNED) DAY + INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX( 0x0000A249004576D0 ),9,8), 16, 10) AS SIGNED)* 10000/3 MICROSECOND AS DATETIME)) AS newdate
```