# Convert SQL Server date to PostgreSQL timestamp

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, date, type-conversion, date-conversion

In SQL Server I have field of type date.
When I export data to SQL file, I have following output for this field:

```
0x2F9D0A00 AS Date
```

I'm trying to convert this hex value as follows:

```
SELECT '1900-01-01'::date +
(('x'||substring(x::text,3,8))::bit(32)::int::text||'days')::interval
FROM (VALUES 
  ('0x2F9D0A00'))  as x(x);
```

But in Postgres get this error:

```
ERROR: timestamp out of range
SQL state: 22008
```

How can I convert this hex to timestamp?

Update: 0x2F9D0A00 is an int 798820864. This is not milliseconds, seconds, minutes or hours, cause none of this measures doesn't give me correct date, which was in SQL Server. What is it?

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580700/microsoft-hex-dates

Comment: Actually I looked through StackOverflow for this conversion. Issue is that this hex is really weird. In int it will be - 798820864, which I suppose causes this error. Too much for Postgres?